# Accumulating results while using them in Isabelle/Isar

Tags: isabelle, isar

Sometimes in a proof I find myself needing to accumulate results, but also needing use the last result, so I end up using "`also then`" for that purpose:

```
proof
  have ...
  also then have ...
  also then have ...
  ultimately show ...
qed
```

I feel like there are more idiomatic ways to this that I don't know about. On the other hand, this might be the standard way to do it and encouraged by the community.

So in light of that, I have two questions:

1. Is using "`also then`" discouraged?
2. If so, what alternatives can I use to accumulate results *while* using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by providing some background. You have breached the subject known as calculational reasoning in Isabelle. Calculation reasoning is described in subsection 1.2 of the document [*The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual*](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf).

Two of the most common patterns for calculational reasoning are

```
  have "a R b" sorry
  also have "b R c" sorry
  also have "c R d" sorry
  finally have "a R d" by assumption
```

(where `R` is a transitive relation, such as `=`, written using the infix notation) and

```
  have P sorry
  moreover have Q  sorry
  moreover have R sorry
  ultimately have S by (rule assms(1))
```

The commands like `also` and `moreover` use an additional fact `calculation` to store additional information. For example, as the calculation in the first example above proceeds, the fact `calculation` changes in the following manner

```
  have "a R b" sorry
  also have "b R c" (*calculation: a R b*) sorry 
  also have "c R d" (*calculation: a R c*) sorry
  finally have "a R d" by assumption
```

In this case, the transitivity rule of `R` is used for chaining the predicates. Thus, the final goal can be discharged by assumption. The situation is different for the `moreover ... ultimately` pattern:

```
  have P sorry
  moreover have Q (*calculation: P*) sorry
  moreover have R (*calculation: P, Q*) sorry
  ultimately have S (*P ⟹ Q ⟹ R ⟹ S*) by (rule assms(1))
```

In this case, the fact `calculation` merely accumulates all previous results.

The implementation of the calculational reasoning is explained in subsection 6.3 of the document [*The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual*](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf). However, I omit the details in this post.

---

I will now make an attempt to answer your questions in the context of what was stated above.

> Is using "also then" discouraged?

I believe that this is not, necessarily, discouraged and there are some instances of the use of this pattern in the AFP. However, I can imagine that for this specific pattern this would be a reasonably uncommon use case.

> If so, what alternatives can I use to accumulate results while using
> them?

I believe that if you, indeed, need to merely accumulate results (while, possibly, using them in the intermittent steps), the best pattern to use would be `moreover ... ultimately`. However, of course, this depends on what exactly is meant by the "accumulation of results".

---

Remark 1

I hope that from the discussion above it is apparent that the use of `also` in conjunction with `ultimately` is very unconventional. In most cases, it makes little sense to use such a pattern.

---

Remark 2

The pattern `also ... finally` is often used in conjunction with the abbreviation `...`:

```
  have "a R b" sorry
  also have "... R c" sorry
  also have "... R d" sorry
  finally have "a R d" by assumption
```

Of course, the benefits can only become apparent if `b` and `c` are sufficiently long subterms.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I think I didn't quite get what you meant by "*I believe that if you, indeed, need [...], the best pattern to use would be `moreover ... ultimately`"*. Since using *only* `moreover` doesn't automatically let me use the previous fact(s), did you mean something along the lines of "`moreover then have ...`" or "`moreover have ... using calculation ...`"? and, since we're already here, is it discouraged to use "`using calculation`" directly?

Comment: Indeed, you can combine `moreover ... ultimately` with `then` and `from`, you can also use `calculation` explicitly if you wish to. A good way to check whether a paradigm that you are thinking about using is acceptable is to look for it in the source code of Isabelle/HOL using the standard search functionality of Isabelle/jEdit (or, perhaps, in the AFP). If you find that this pattern was used by more than one author, then it is very likely that you will not be discouraged from using it :-).